# Meaning of "rather ... nor"

Tags: meaning

> The folks said they’d rather starve nor eat the corn meal.

Does it mean 'to choose starve than to eat the corn meal'?

The context is as below:

> Oh, yes, I mind the famine years. An’ the cornmeal that the ‘Mericans
>   sent. The folks said they’d rather starve nor eat it. We didn’t know
>   how to cook it.

Comment: The original is badly formed. You can fix it by changing *rather* to *neither* or *nor* to *than (to)*.

Comment: @Lawrence Maybe because it's Irish English... I have added more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OED, Scottish English uses the expression "rather ... nor" where Standard English uses "rather ... than".

I have only been able to find a few citations online (most are a little old), but they indicate that the expression is (or was) also used in Irish English:

> God knows, sur, I'd rather die nor go!
>   <sub>[By Thrasna River: The Story of a Townland](https://books.google.com/books?id=l0xekQVGW7AC&pg=PA395)</sub>

> Why, them ponies is like game-cocks—*they'd rather die nor run!*"
>   <sub>[Harper's New Monthly Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pd5IAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA480)</sub>

Comment: Buy me a River!